# os.stat doesn't update when large file is being copied

Tags: python, windows, file

I'm using stat to check if a file is still being transferred, but it's not working. If I copy a large file over the network (talking hundreds of gigabytes, they can take several minutes) and I run the script

```
from os import stat
from time import sleep
While True:
    stat("thefile.foo")
    sleep(2)
```

I expect to see either the time or the size changing, but it stays the same. Is there anything else I can use to check if a file is still transferring? This is on a windows server, unfortunately.

[image: screen shot of stats not updating]

I tried this script, to actually read the file:

```
import sys
finished=False
oldgb=0
while not finished:
f=open(thefile,"rb")
samp=f.read(1)
gb=0
while samp!= b'':
    sys.stdout.flush()
    gb+=1000000000
    f.seek(gb)
    samp=f.read(1)
    print(gb/1000000000,samp)       
f.close()
print(oldgb, gb)
if gb>oldgb:
    oldgb=gb
else:
    finished=True
```

And noticed that while the file was being copied the bytes that hadn't been copied yet were initialised to zero, hence the file size not updating. I might use a checksum to check if the file has changed instead.

Comment: Doesn't this require that the other process cooperates by performing flushes ?

Comment: os.path.getsize(filepath) can also be used to get the file size.

Comment: getsize() doesn't work either - it reports the final size of the file.

Comment: Do you have any control over the transfer process?  Renaming the file when the transfer is complete is a reliable signal, if your transfer mechanism allows for that (e.g., `ftp`, `sftp`).

Comment: I'm thinking I might just seek backwards from the end of the file until it stops seeing all zeroes, then sleep, and do the same thing again, comparing how far it seeks each time. Files with big sections of zeros in it will cause problems though.

Comment: The files are in a dropbox folder, so lots of users, no control over the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's the hackalicious solution: first I installed [sysinternals handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896655%28en-us%29.aspx). I use that to see if the files have any open handles, thusly:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
filename="file.foo"
finished = False
while not finished:
    handlesactive=subprocess.check_output("handle.exe")
    activehandles=str(handlesactive).count(filename)
    if activehandles == 0: finished = True
    print("still busy")
    sleep(2)
```

edit: this works for files being transferred on the machine itself - eg copied from one local file to another, however no file handles are created if a file is being transferred by an external machine. However the mtime of the file *is* changed in that case (fortunately).

So for my use - in a script to scan a folder and check for new files - I ended up using a combination of checking for handles (for local files) and checking for mtime and size (for external files).

Comment: Powershell is how I tackle it these days BTW.